# CSS clear float

Tags: css, css-float

I have a question about css `clear float`.

My question is when I declare `div{float:left;}` to all the page, then in some part, I still want some div display center of the screen, like `width:960px;margin:0 auto`. How to clear this `div's` float?

see code in: http://jsfiddle.net/37wnT/  and review in http://jsfiddle.net/37wnT/show/

I need `div#nav` and `div#content` these two div center of the screen, but other div still obey the rule `float:left;`

Comment: "It still obeying the rule of `float: left;`" means that you're being way too restrictive with your CSS. As you can probably gather from this, it's really bad practice to set something as generic as `div { float: left; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code little bit. take a look.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.main{float:left;}
#header{width:100%;height:100px;}
#nav{clear:both;width:800px;margin:0 auto;}
.nav{width:200px;text-align:center;font:16px/150%;}
#wrap{width:100%;height:100%;}
#content{clear:both !important;width:960px;height:100%;margin:0 auto;}
.col{width:300px;height:300px;margin:0 10px 0 10px;background:red;display:block;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
    <div id="nav">
        <div class="nav main">home</div>
        <div class="nav main">info</div>
        <div class="nav main">products</div>
        <div class="nav main">cantact</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="col main" >ds</div>
        <div class="col main">ds</div>
        <div class="col main">ds</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EbhjZ/1/)

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col" >2</div>
    <div class="col" style="clear:left;margin-top:10px">3</div><br> <-- changes here
</div>
```

I am not sure if this is what you want.